# NSNumber instance will not retain value

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, object

Im using an nsnumber as a counter but its not retaining its value.  It may be a pointer issue because its showing up as 13 in my init statement but its null in my tap.  I'm not sure where or why this is happening.  I've never really messed with the automatically generated _instanceValue for my properties.  I've always used self.propertyName as an accessor.  I believe this may have something to do with it.

header file

```
@interface PezStoryViewer : UIViewController


@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *counter;


-(id)initWithScene:(NSArray *)scenes;
+(void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

m file

```
-(id)initWithScene:(NSArray *)scenes{

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    //reverse array order
    scenes = [[scenes reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

    //set counter
    _counter = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInteger:[scenes count]];
    NSLog(@"_counter = %@", _counter);

    //initialize subviews
    //and other stuff
    }


 return self;

}



-(void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

NSLog(@"tap");

NSLog(@"_counter = %@", _counter);
NSUInteger i = [_counter unsignedIntegerValue];
i--;
NSLog(@"counter = %d", i);


if ([gesture.view isKindOfClass:[PezFrontImageView class]]) {
    //3 Steps
    //1: pop off subview
    [gesture.view removeFromSuperview];
    //2: if next view is a video, play it
    //3: initialize new frontView under the existing backView
}


if (i==7) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

_counter = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:i];


}

+ (id)sharedInstance {
static id sharedInstance;
@synchronized(self) {
    if (!sharedInstance)
        sharedInstance = [[PezStoryViewer alloc] init];
    return sharedInstance;
}
}
```

tap gesture on my subview that is of type UIImageView custom class

```
    //add tapGesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[PezStoryViewer sharedInstance] action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: Update your question showing how `_counter` is declared. BTW - It's much easier to simply do: `_counter = @(scenes.count);` or `_counter = @(i);`.

Comment: Could it be that you're not initing your view controller with `initWithScene:`?

Comment: I am. I even logged 13 as the value of the counter in the     initWithScene: method

Comment: What calls `viewTapped:`? Where do you setup the gesture recognizer? Why is this view controller a singleton? Why did you declare a class method named `viewTapped:` in addition to implementing an instance method of the same name?

Comment: A subview on the view controller.  Check out my update its at the bottom

Comment: Are you sure you're calling viewTapped: on the same instance of PezStoryViewer that was constructed via initWithScene:?

Comment: I thought i was since it was a shared instance and already allocated.  I updated my code with the shared instance implimentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your `sharedInstance` method does not call `initWithScene:`. It just calls `init`. So you never initialize the `counter` property.

You really shouldn't be setting up your view controller as a singleton. Just create the view controller when needed and use the `initWithScene:` method.

Comment: Then how would I access the PezStoryViewer Controller which holds my viewTapped: method from my UIImageView subview file which holds my tapGesture recognizer method (see last code snippet)       Thats the only reason i needed to use it as a shared instance

Comment: Sounds like you have things all messed up. The view controller should be setting up the tap gesture, not the image view.

Comment: I could do that.  I just did it this way because my viewcontroller will be adding and dismissing a bunch of imageViews so i just added the tapgesture into the image views init statement